# Forward search doesn't work (from TexMaker to SumatraPDF)

Tags: texmaker, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

When I try to press `ctrl`+`space` (or `F7`) in order to activate the forward search it doesn't work. The `pdfLatex` field is

> pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

The `external viewer` field is

> "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -1 -s @%.tex %.pdf

I also tried to compile it 3 times before the forward search but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Any reason you want to use sumatra when texmaker comes with its own pdf viewer that supports synctex out of the box and which can run in its own window if needed to.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but sumatra works better for me.